# What can I change with the Fantasia potion, and is there a way to get more of them?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

As part of Veteran Rewards, I received the [Fantasia Potion](http://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Fantasia) a while back.It says that if I drink it I'll be able to edit my appearance (and, apparently, gender) the next time I log on.

I'd like to use it, as I originally made my main character back during beta and didn't make the decisions that looking back I feel I would have if I'd known a bit better, but as it's a one-shot item I'd like to know a little more about the limitations before I use it and wind up compounding one set of poor decisions with another.

1. The potion mentions appearance and gender. Does this also include any of: race, birthdate, voice, victory pose?
2. Are there any ways to obtain more of these potions in case I wind up regretting my decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kv8cnHW8VMo) shows you how to use the Fantasia Potion. There are a few things which you have to do before you can use it, for example taking off all your gear.

1.) Yes, you will be able to change your race, gender, etc the next time you will login. The Fantasia Potion gives you the chance to change everything except your starting class.

2.) Additional Fantasia potions can only be purchased in the Mog Station for real money.

Comment: They are adding the ability to purchase Fantasia Potions in the 2.28 update, which should hit June 4th or 5th, 2014.